# Dynamic added div with onclick link

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm adding some amount of div based on the xml list which contain some data and url
Currently trying to use onClick but it doesn't seems right on the js that loads the div part.

```
 //retrieve each of the data field from ITEM
var url = item.find('url').text();
var image = item.find('project-img').text();
var title = item.find('id').text();
var desc = item.find('desc').text();
var html;

//Embed them into HTML code
html = '<div class="project"><img src="' + image + '" alt="' + title + '" />';
html += '<div class="info">';
html += '<div class="title">'+title+'</div>';
html += '<div role="button" class="launch" onclick="window.open('+url+',"mywindow");">Launch Website</div>';
html += '<div role="button" class="more">View More</div>';
html += '</div></div>';
```

I think it somehow get mess up on the adding 'url' part with ' or "
Or there would be a much easier way to call a link on such situation?

Comment: you could put a `<a href="<yourUrlHere>"></a>` around the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your requirement correct syntax would be

```
html += '<div role="button" class="launch" onclick="window.open(\''+url+'\',\'mywindow\');">Launch Website</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error (the only one i could spot), so try the following:

```
onclick="window.open('+url+',\'mywindow\');"
```